# Traversing associations inside of a Hibernate Criteria OR query

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have two objects that look something like this:

```
public class Foo{
    List<Bar> bars;
    String name;
}

public class Bar {
    String value;
}
```

I would like to use the Hibernate Criteria API to make an OR query that involves both of the  properties of `Foo`. Specifically, I want to select all the `Foos` that have the `name` "somevalue" OR have a `Bar` in their `bars` collection that has a `value` of "anothervalue".

I know how to do these independently:

```
createCriteria(Foo.class).add(Restrictions.eq("name","somevalue"));

and

createCriteria(Foo.class).createCriteria("bars").add(Restrictions.eq("value","anothervalue"));
```

(taken from [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-associations))

but when I try to put these on either side of a Restrictions.or() statement, it gives me a compile error. So, my question is: is this even possible using Criteria, or will I have to use HQL or plain SQL?

Answer (score 0):

Just from the top of my head, would this work?

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Foo.class);
criteria.createAlias("bars", "bar");
String value = "somevalue";
criteria.add(Restrictions.or(Restrictions.eq("name", value), Restrictions.eq("bar.name", value)));
```